# Browsers dispay wrong font

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I've got little problem with font-face. I've generated font-face for web-site, font is called 'Bebas Neue'. It works perfectly in Safari, but in other browser some text elements use the right font, some don't, although if you click on them in browser developer tools you'll see there 'Bebas Neue' as a font.

Here's a link to a web-site: http://glebgrg4.bget.ru. You can see the wrong font displaying on the big green button on top and in menu. How do I solve this bug?

Comment: I've found out that the problem is that font doesn't display cyrillic characters correctly, that's strange because this font supports them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you didn't set Cyrillic Subsetting. Simply on fontsquirrel:

EXPERT... -> Subsetting: ->  Custom Subsetting... -> Language: -> Select Cyrillic.

Comment: Just did it a minute ago, it helped) Anyway, thanks.